# Upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^nk_i$ given $\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i^3}k_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, inequality

Suppose that $n>0$ is an integer, and $\{k_i\}_i$ is a positive integer sequence. If the following inequality holds:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i^3}k_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}. 
$$
I want to know the upper bound of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nk_i$. I guess it should be $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks. I have modified the title.

Comment: You are right! I have changed it

Comment: It seems intuitively that the way to maximize $\sum k_i$ while staying within the bound would simply be to maximize the last term while minimizing the rest (because $k_1$ is restricted to be max $\log(n)$ while $k_n$ can be almost $n^3\log(n)$ so we can "gain" the most by adjusting this last term up). This would be to take $k_1=k_2=\ldots=k_{n-1} = 1$ with $k_n$ being the largest one you can do. This should give you a $\mathcal{O}(n^3\log(n))$ bound atleast.

Comment: @Winther Thanks! As mentioned in stochasticboy321, the upper bound should be $\mathcal{O}(n^3\log(n))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the worst case $\sum k_i$ can be $\Theta(n^3 \log n)$. The upper bound is trivial: $\sum_{i\le n} k_i/i^3 \ge \sum_{i \le n} k_i /n^3,$ so $\sum k_i \le H_n n^3 = n^3 \log n + O(n^3),$ where $H_n = \sum_{i \le n} 1/i = \log n + \gamma + o(1)$.  A sequence achieving $\Omega(n^3 \log n)$ is $k_1 = \dots = k_{n-1} = 1,$ $k_n = \lfloor n^3 (H_n - \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} 1/i^3)\rfloor,$ which almost saturates the upper bound, provided that $n$ is so large that $H_n \ge 1 + \sum_{i = 2}^{n-1} 1/i^3,$ which holds for all $n > 20$ (and maybe sooner). Note that this is more or less the same lower bound as the one Winther mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is an optimization problem in which all constraints are linear:

Maximize the objective function $$f(k):=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nk_i$$
under the constraint
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i^3}k_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$$

First, note that the optimium is achieved at $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{i^3}k_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$, for if we had a solution in which the constraint is strict, we could increase a $k_i$, thereby increasing the value of the objective function.

Now, assume $k_1,...,k_n$ was an optimal solution. If $k_i>0$ for $i\in\{1,...,n-1\}$, then we can increase the value of the objective function by setting $k_i=0$ and increasing the value of $k_n$ as much as the constraint allows.

Therefore, the optimal solution is achieved at $k_1=...=k_{n-1}=0, k_n = n^3\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i$.

You can now get your upper bound by looking at the asymptotics of the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you provide a new insigt. I think the KKT condition may be useful for the proof.

Comment: Given that the bound is sharp, KKT simplifies to Lagrange. But given that the objective and constraints are linear, you'll find that the method is less helpful than one might think. My answer gives a proof, you just need to formalize the parts I skipped because I deemed them obvious. That said, given that the constraint is an equality constraint, just substituting it into the objective works as well.